# Create sublists with duplicate list elements

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create sublists for list elements sharing the same base:

```
listRaw = ['AKS/STB', 'SBHS/AME', 'SBJ/OAK', 'SBJ/ALS', 'AKS/OSMX', 'SBHS/ABNX', 'AKS/AKX']
desiredOutput = [['AKS/STB', 'AKS/OSMX', 'AKS/AKX'], ['SBHS/AME', 'SBHS/ABNX'], ['SBJ/OAK', 'SBJ/ALS']]
```

I've tried to first isolate the base from each list element using:

```
def commonNumerator(self):
    checkPosition = self.find('/')
    commonNumerator = self[:checkPosition]
    return commonNumerator

listRawModified = [commonNumerator(x) for x in listRaw]
print(listRawModified)
```

which gets me:

```
['AKS', 'SBHS', 'SBJ', 'SBJ', 'AKS', 'SBHS', 'AKS']
```

but from then I don't know how to proceed to get to the desired ouput.

Can someone explain to me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical usecase for [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

listRaw = ['AKS/STB', 'SBHS/AME', 'SBJ/OAK', 'SBJ/ALS', 'AKS/OSMX', 'SBHS/ABNX', 'AKS/AKX']

def key(s):
    return s.split('/')[0]

[list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(listRaw, key=key), key=key)]
# [['AKS/STB', 'AKS/OSMX', 'AKS/AKX'], ['SBHS/AME', 'SBHS/ABNX'], ['SBJ/OAK', 'SBJ/ALS']]
```

The `key()` function helps in extracting the sorting/grouping key: `key('AKS/STB')` == `'AKS'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to split each element and create a dictionary and then construct your desired output from that dictionary, e.g.:

```
In []:
d = {}
for i in listRaw:
    k, v = i.split('/')
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
[['/'.join([k, v]) for v in d[k]] for k in d]

Out[]:
[['AKS/STB', 'AKS/OSMX', 'AKS/AKX'], ['SBHS/AME', 'SBHS/ABNX'], ['SBJ/OAK', 'SBJ/ALS']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical usecase for itertools. But you could also consider storing the values in a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
listRaw = ['AKS/STB', 'SBHS/AME', 'SBJ/OAK', 'SBJ/ALS', 'AKS/OSMX', 'SBHS/ABNX', 'AKS/AKX']

for item in listRaw:
    i,y = item.split('/')
    d[i].append(y)

print(dict(d))

# {'AKS': ['STB', 'OSMX', 'AKX'], 'SBHS': ['AME', 'ABNX'], 'SBJ': ['OAK', 'ALS']}
```

You can then access the values to `AKS` with a simple command as:

```
d['AKS'] # ['STB', 'OSMX', 'AKX']
```